# How to merge a row into a subcolumn in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge the years that end with '0s'(1850s, 1860s etc) into one subcolumn, just like in the [original database](https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/All_U.S._Hurricanes.html)

I imported the table in excel, but it doesn't read the ['0s'] columns as one row. Instead it splits the subcolumns into cells.

My code so far is only this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Enas/Python_Data/Hurricanes/hurricanes.xlsx')
df.head()

 df.loc[df['Year'].str.contains('0s')]
```

[head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzoVj.png)

[the 0s that I want make a subcolumn each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jguxQ.png)

Comment: There is no column whose name ends with `0s` in the mentioned link, rather there are rows whose year ends with `0s`. Did you mean extracting these rows?

Comment: I apologize since I didn't ask properly. I meant that I want each row whose year ends with 0s(1900s for example) to be merged into a subcolumn just like in the original database. Excel for some reasons splits the subcolumns into multiple cells and distributes it into the rest of the data.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with "subcolumn"... Do you mean the horizontal sections on the webpage?

Comment: And could you show us what your dataframe currently looks like (or the head, at least)?